# Function on-load not loading

Tags: javascript, function, onload

I'm new to Javascript and this is "my" "filtering function" for my project:

This is my function "auth" to authenticate my label:

```
function auth() {
if ($('#Resultat_mobilelabel_resultat:contains("Nautnes")').length > 0) {
    document.getElementById('Resultat_mobilelabel_sted').innerHTML = 'Nautnesveien nord';
} else {
    alert("some error")
        Appery.navigateTo('startScreen', {
            reverse: false
        });
    }
}
```

and this is how im trying to run the function:

```
// On Load
screen_1665_onLoad = Resultat_onLoad = function() {
    auth();
}
```

But somehow it does not load the function when the page is loaded...
Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: You need to call either `screen_1665_onLoad` or `Resultat_onLoad` from somewhere.

Comment: Did none of the answers work for you? If one did, you should mark it as the answer so that others can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`(screen_1665_onLoad = function() { 
    auth();
})();`

That should run when the page loads.

Then again, you're using jQuery so why not go for the stock-syntax:

`$(function() {

    auth(); // This is your function-call, which will run once jQuery determines the document is ready

});`

Comment: Worked like a champ! :D
with my lack of coding knowledge i cinda get how your code works but i dont get this part "{ auth(); })();"

Comment: The `function() { auth(); }` is just declaring an anonymous function, which then invokes your `auth()`-function.  

However the anonymous function won't RUN until it's called, and a good time to run it is when jQuery is ready to interact with the document. To run the anonymous function at that time, we wrap everything with jQuery's `$();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like you are assigning screen_165_onLoad with a function than actually calling the function

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
    $(document).ready(function(){
     auth();
    });

at the end of the page